# GCP memorystore redis latency high on 1000 TPS

Tags: google-cloud-platform, redis, google-cloud-memorystore

I am working on GKE and GCP memory store Redis, Redis giving high latency, up to 500 000 requests Redis behavior is as expected, once requests more than 500k, Redis adding more latency and response is very slow.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking 500K ops/second than that's pretty much what you can expect from a single memory store instance.

You can shard out on the client side or look at other hosted options for Redis on Google cloud that do offer more scaling.